# clicking on a specific ion-item button triggers other buttons

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i used ng-repeat to generate an ion-list. inside each ion-item there's a toggle-behaviored button that changes color when tapped and untapped. however when i tap on the button in one ion-item, the other buttons from other ion-items also gets tapped and changes their colors. how should i go about this?

```
<ion-list id="listOfCandidates-list6">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in itemList" class="item-candidates alternaterow item-thumbnail-left" id="listOfCandidates-list-item8">
   <img src="img/tRk31wFSmS2hKHXnIAOZ_candidateicon.png">
   <br>
    <div class="col1">
    <h4>Name: {{item.name}}</h4><h4>Candidate No.: {{item.number}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
    <button class="button button-clear icon ion-star button-energized" ng-model="singleTog" ng-click="toggleButton(item.name)" ng-class="singleTog.clicked?'button-energized':'button-dark'" ></button>
    <button ng-click="goDetail(item.name,item.number)" class="button btn-small btn-primary">View</button>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and here's my controller.js code:

```
$scope.favoriteList = []
$scope.singleTog = {}

$scope.toggleButton = function(candidateName)
{
 $scope.singleTog.clicked=!$scope.singleTog.clicked
 if($scope.singleTog.clicked==true)
 {
   if($scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) == -1) //does not exist in array
   {
    $scope.favoriteList.push(candidateName);
   }
 }
 else
 {
   if($scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) != -1) //exists in array
   {
     var index = $scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName);
     $scope.favoriteList.splice(index, 1);   
   }
 }

 alert('favorites = ' + $scope.favoriteList);
}
```

Comment: Your items in the ng-repeat are all being bound to the same object instance as defined in your ng-model directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the index to the function which you are calling to trigger an event.

```
<button class="button button-clear icon ion-star button-energized" ng-model="singleTog" ng-click="toggleButton(item.name,$index)" ng-class="singleTog[$index] ?'button-energized':'button-dark'" ></button>
<button ng-click="goDetail(item.name,item.number)" class="button btn-small btn-primary">View</button>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.singleTog =[];

$scope.toggleButton = function(candidateName,index)
{
$scope.singleTog[index]=!$scope.singleTog[index];
 if($scope.singleTog[index])
 {
   if($scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) == -1) //does not exist in array
   {
    $scope.favoriteList.push(candidateName);
   }
 }
 else
 {
   if($scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName) != -1) //exists in array
   {
     var index = $scope.favoriteList.indexOf(candidateName);
     $scope.favoriteList.splice(index, 1);   
   }
 }
alert('favorites = ' + $scope.favoriteList);

}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the input. it works, however i can only select one item, is there a way to be able to click multiple buttons without affecting the other buttons?

Comment: can you elaborate what was your exact requirement

Comment: button for each item in list must change to color yellow once clicked, then change back to color black once same button is clicked again. also, it should be able to click on more than one button... it's kind of like having a checkbox for each item that can be selected and unselected.

Comment: i just made few modifications to the existing code. hope,it will help you